# Dynamically fetching matching data for each table row using AJAX

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

The rows below are generated dynamically

```
<input id="soid0" name="soid[0].name" type="text" />
<input id="soid1" name="soid[1].name" type="text" />
<input id="soid2" name="soid[2].name" type="text" />
```

And as I traverse through the text field Ajax query should call the back end and get the matching data if any existed

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#soid0" ).autocomplete({
            source: "/myapp/soid.htm"
        });

    });
```

The query works but I want it to work for all the dynamically generated rows `#soid0`,`#soid1`? In short, I need one query that works for all the text field.

Thanks

Comment: use $('input[type="text"]')

Comment: Will try this one too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## By Attribute Selector

---

Use an attribute selector in combination with the `^` starts with selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name^="soid"]' ).autocomplete({
        source: "/myapp/soid.htm"
    });
});
```

Note that the jquery documentation advises against this selector when classes can be used, stating:

> However it will be slower than using a class selector so leverage
>   classes, if you can, to group like elements.

## By Class(Preferred Method)

---

Or apply a class to each input:

**HTML**

```
<input id="soid0" class="soid" name="soid[0].name" type="text" />
<input id="soid1" class="soid" name="soid[1].name" type="text" />
<input id="soid2" class="soid" name="soid[2].name" type="text" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.soid' ).autocomplete({
        source: "/myapp/soid.htm"
    });
});
```

## By Tag

---

Or if these are the only inputs on the page, use a tag selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input' ).autocomplete({
        source: "/myapp/soid.htm"
    });
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/QqeLp/

Comment: @java_dude I had to update the attribute selector, but I would recommend going with the classes.  Jquery Documentation agrees.

Comment: @java_dude Excellent, that is the best approach!